# Update advanced filter for a range which has new rows added

Tags: vba, advanced-filter

I have a worksheet containing a list of criteria in cells A1 to J2. Row 1 is the header.

Below i have a a table with all my data items. Cells A8 to J with a dynamic numbre of rows

```
Sheets("D0022").Range("A8:" & Sheets("D0022").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("D0022").Range("a1:j2"), Unique:=True
```

When i run this i get an 
Runtime 1004
Application defined or object defined error

Can i have assistance on why my VBA code does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing of `Sheets("D0022").Range("A8:" & Sheets("D0022").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(...`

with

`Sheets("D0022").Range("A8:J" & Sheets("D0022").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(...`

`"A8:J"` instead of `"A8:"`.

Otherwise you do not set the column of the range.

`Sheets("D0022").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row` calculates only the last row of column J:J...

Comment: Thank you so much i spent an age trying see what i missed. Thank you for the second pair of yes